# Why can't display google map v2 on real phone Android 2.3.1

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Below is my code:
layoutmap.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

EMaps2 .java

```
public class EMaps2 extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutmap);
}
}
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.daitran.mapversion2.EMaps2 "
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBTLEIcHn7wKQQC_q6y0YcJ7Ffw03PHfHs" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
```

I checked on my real device having Android 4.0.3 , Map displays OK.
But when i run on my real device with  Android 2.3.1, Map is not displayed and shows message :

**This app won't run without google play service, which are missing from you phone.**

How to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: how you install the apk file in real device.

Comment: I upload to dropbox And download install.

Comment: you export the apk file from developing environment.am correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install [Google Play Service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) in your device from Google play store.

Comment: I click to button Get Google Play Service . It show dialog [The requested item could not be found]

Comment: Have you follow the above provided link

Comment: Why do i search on Market not display Google Play services?

Comment: My phone can't install Google Play Service from your link provided.

Comment: Can i auto install Google Play Service when user install my app?

Comment: Try this:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.gms"));
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: I can't auto install with Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.gms")); startActivity(intent);   It show dialog [The requested item could not be found]

Comment: Have you way not must install?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity extends FragmentActivity. This works fine from API 11 +, but android 2.3.1 is below 11.

Replace your FragmentActivity with android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

```
public class EMaps2 extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity{

...

}
```

This gives compatibility for lower versions of API also.
Make Sure you have android.support.v4.jar in your libs, or referenced.